# randomly show (shuffle) divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of divs like this:

[image: example]

I need to shuffle them when one of red divs is clicked but a clicked div should always be swapped with a yellow div.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7RfLU/)

```
$('.box-red').click(function() {
    var container = $('#container');
    var nodes = container.children();
    for (var i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        container.append(nodes.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * nodes.length)));
    }
});
```

thanks

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having?

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Zw2T6/1/)

1. put in random colors
2. click on a box
3. remember the box name and class
4. randomize ALL boxes again
5. change the "clicked" box to the different class

I tried using rgb codes, but was not getting consistent results, then here on SO, someone updated
an old answer and said this type of thing might best be handled by changing class - a Eureka! moment. Seems to work. I'd like to play some more with rgb...not trivial.

JS

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){
    getboxcolor = $(this).hasClass('blue');
    getboxnum = $(this).attr('id');
    newcolors();
    if( getboxcolor )
    {
     $( '#' + getboxnum ).removeClass( 'blue' );
     $( '#' + getboxnum ).addClass( 'green' );
     }
     else
    {
     $( '#' + getboxnum ).removeClass( 'green' );
     $( '#' + getboxnum ).addClass( 'blue' );
     }
     getboxcolor = '';
     getboxnum = 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have made certain changes to the fiddle.

First of all, the shuffling you are doing may not be a good shuffle as you've chances of duplicating the nodes that you are trying to shuffle. Which makes your shuffle not that effective.

I've used a variant of the [Knuth-Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) Shuffle.

```
function shuffle(nodes) {
    var length = nodes.length;
    var randomPick, randomSwap;
    for (var index = length; index > 0; index--) {
        randomPick = Math.floor(Math.random() * index);
        randomSwap = nodes[index - 1];
        nodes[index - 1] = nodes[randomPick];
        nodes[randomPick] = randomSwap;

    }
    return nodes;
}
```

The important part about ensuring the red-box (if it existed at position 'x') is replaced by a yellow-box, is to make sure that you store that index first.

If the element at that index post the shuffle is not a yellow-box, then you find the first yellow-box and then swap it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/3u9ez/) where you can see it being used. Note that this is forked from yours, but I have changed the HTML.

```
$('.box-red').click(function () {

    //Important to store the index at which this red-node was present.
    var currentNodeIndex = $(this).index();

    var container = $('#container');

    var nodes = container.children();

    //Shuffles the node array.
    nodes = shuffle(nodes);

    console.log("Shuffled nodes", nodes);

    //If the current node index does not have a yellow-box, then go ahead and replace it.    
    if (!$(nodes[currentNodeIndex]).hasClass('yellow')) {
        for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
            if (index != currentNodeIndex && $(nodes[index]).hasClass("box-yellow")) {
                var redNode = nodes[currentNodeIndex];
                nodes[currentNodeIndex] = nodes[index];
                nodes[index] = redNode;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Finally, build the complete node tree again.
    container.append(nodes);

});
```

**Update**
Updated code based on King King's Suggestion

Comment: There are 2 points (which are not good in your code). Firstly we don't need a separate loop to find the `yellow-box` after shuffling. We can check for the `yellow-box` right in the loop in the `shuffle` function, remember that **instance**. Then after shuffling, we can just swap that instance and the clicked red box (the current node). The second is you don't need to loop through the shuffled nodes to append each one to the `container`, you just need to call `container.append(nodes)`.

Comment: Just calling container.append(nodes) would not be the right thing to do. You've to recall that the container already contains the required nodes. Appending it with the same "set" will be different than appending it one by one (for a good shuffle). You can fork the fiddle and see the behavior yourself. As for figuring out the `yellow-box` in the shuffle...yeah, that's something that can be done. I'll leave it to the OP ;)

Comment: have you read the documentation of `append`? ***You've to recall that the container already contains the required nodes*** when you add each node to it, isn't this the case you said?

Comment: from documentation **.append( content [, content ] )** in which **content**: *DOM element, **array of elements**, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements*

Comment: BTW, I've also written a demo myself and using `append(nodes)`, it works great, don't dare me to try it myself.

Comment: @King King: No need to be rude. I did try **not** using the loop for append. The "shuffle" experience when you leave JQuery to decide how to append the set is not as good as when you leave it as is. That's why I said you should probably fork and check out the fiddle.

Comment: You said I was wrong first, it's totally unacceptable. Unless the truth is I was wrong. I don't know how experienced you are (about jQuery) but `for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) { container.append(nodes[index]);}` showed me the answer, while that loop can just be replaced by `container.append(nodes)`. You did not even try it, search for it and told me to try it myself (to see that I was wrong?)

Comment: @King King I wrote that fiddle, so to test your answer, I simply removed the loop. And (big apology coming up), I did not modify `container.append(nodes[index]` to `container.append(nodes)`. So, my apologies to you. That's why I thought the experience looked different.